# [AS3]gotoAndPlay(frameLabel, sceneName) failed

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a frame (call this "x") in Scene1, and try to go to another frame, whose frame label is "Here", in Scene2, when the button "btn" on "x" is clicked. Here's my code in "x":

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, direct); 
stop(); 
function direct(e:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("Here", "Scene2"); 
}
```

This does not work. I got some information in the output window, it said "ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label Scene2 not found in scene Here. "

It seems that Flash regonized "Here" as a scene name so I also tried this:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("Scene2", "Here");
```

but it said "Scene Here not found." However, the codes below both work:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene2"); 
/*---*/
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("Here"); //In the case that frame Here is in Scene1
```

I've googled a lot but still been stuck here. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you provide a FLA file?

Comment: I'm using CS4. I hope this can work on your version and thanks for trying to help me. http://goo.gl/29iZDj

Comment: It works in Flash CC and Flash CS6.